# PHP - Check for duplicate before writing to CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a contest form for our company that writes to a csv file. It is only one entry per household, so at time submission I want to check to see if the submitted address has already been entered into the csv file before it is written. I have seen where you can use SELECT with a database, but I don't know how to do it with a `.csv` Here is the code:

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Enter Now") {

         $errorMessage = "";
         $aClass = "";

         if(empty($_POST['name'])){$errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your name!</li>";}
         if(empty($_POST['email'])){$errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your email!</li>";}
         if(empty($_POST['address1'])){$errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your address!</li>";}
         if(empty($_POST['city'])){$errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your city!</li>";}
         if(empty($_POST['postcode'])){$errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your zip code!</li>";}

         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
         $city = $_POST['city'];
         $state = $_POST['state'];
         $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
         $csvData = $name . "," . $email . "," . $address1 . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $postcode ."\n";

         if(empty($errorMessage)){
              $fs = fopen("contest.csv","a");
              fwrite($fs,$csvData);
              fclose($fs);
            header("location: thank you");
              exit;
         }
    }
```

I am thinking I change my fopen to a `r+` in stead of `a` and then read the csv file to check for the address. Then put another if statement where it relays 'duplicate found' or else `fwrite`s the info and sends them to the thank you page.

Comment: You would have to read the csv file and parse each line to see if that variable matches. Have you looked into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org). It provides a SQL mechanism for text files. Then the complete database could be exported to CSV also for subsequent import into spreadsheets

Comment: Flatfiles do have a purpose in certain situations, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: The only problem with DB is that I don't know how to use it yet. That can be fixed though with some self-education. This current "flat file" way seemed way easy and works how I wanted, except I figured checking four duplicants would be an useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the comments, flatfiles are not the best solution for this type of problem, but as you mentioned sometimes it's just easier (and cheaper) to use what's already there and move onto other features.

If you were using a database, you could add a unique constraint on columns where you don't want duplicate data to appear, and this de-dupping capability is handled for you at the database layer. Although you would have to handle the error returned when it attempted to do an insert, its a more elegant solution.

However, if you want to move forward with your CSV solution you will have to parse the existing CSV and extrapolate out the existing addresses, then you can check if the form submitted address already exists.

```
// Pseduo code
User submits form

    Open up existing CSV file

    Step through each entry in csv file
        Store Address in $addresses[] array

    Check if user submitted address exists in $addresses[] array
```

As you can see this solution is non-performant, in that you will have to open, parse, and check every time the form is submitted, however it should accomplish your goal.

Let me know if the psuedo code isn't enough, I can code it out.

--Edit--

Below are a few links to get you started on how to integrate a database solution to solve your problem. These are just to get you started, as there is a wealth of information on the subject:

Database design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design

Vanilla interaction with database (using PHP): http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

ORM interaction with database (using PHP): http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: thanks, this is informative, but I think I will take all your advice and start working on a db solution instead. I can always stand to learn more. Any good tutorials or instructions out there to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @ThomasPool: I updated post with a few links to get you started.